# UILongPressGestureRecognizer does not get deallocated from CollectionViewCell instance

Tags: ios, swift

Ok so I'm out of ideas

Here is my custom UICollectionViewCell class:

```
class baseCViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var mainCV : AnyObject!
    var indexPath : NSIndexPath!

    class func getIdentifier() -> String {
        return NSStringFromClass(self).componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!
    }

    var editGesture : UILongPressGestureRecognizer!

    func initialize(parent:AnyObject, indexPath:NSIndexPath) {
        mainCV = parent as baseCView
        self.indexPath = indexPath

        editGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("edit:"))
        editGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.0
        editGesture.allowableMovement = 100.0
        self.addGestureRecognizer(editGesture)

    }

    func edit(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if (gesture == editGesture) {
            if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began) {
                testinglog("Edit pressed on (\(indexPath.row) in \(indexPath.section))")
            }
        }
    }

    deinit {
        self.removeGestureRecognizer(editGesture)
    }

}
```

My question is .. Why do the gesture objects not dealloc after the cell becomes not-visible (scrolling).

I have tried all I know to force them to dealloc .. with no success

This is how I use the cell:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100;
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CViewCell
        cell.initialize(collectionView, indexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
```

Again .. If I scroll up and down I can see in Instruments the memory count goes up .. and up .. and only up .. being equivalent to a leak .. only not detected.

I commented the part where I add the gestureRecognizer and all is ok (just mentioned it so I don't have to answer if I am sure if the problem is there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collection views reuse cells. As views move offscreen, they are removed from view and placed in a reuse queue instead of being deleted. So, the deinitializer of cell probably will not be called until the collection view is deallocated.

What you are current doing now is adding a new gesture recognizer to the cell every time you dequeue it, this increases memory usage. You should create and initialize the gesture recogniser in the initializer of the cell.

By the way, your cell holds a strong reference back to the collection view, which creates a strong reference cycle, that's not a good thing.

Comment: 1. I see .. so I have to add the gesture only once?
2. I know about the strong reference and I will switch it with a weak one once I add this class to the working project (this is just a test project so far)
3. But if I create and add the gesture in the init(..) method .. wouldn't that just do the same thing .. add another gesture to the cell?

Comment: Yes, you only need to initialize it once.

Comment: Initializers of cells will only be called once.

Comment: ohhhh .. yeah I forgot that :(. Thank you